# Cannot deselect options in mutiselect in IE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have the following select box:

```
<select multiple="" style="width:266px;" class="text_boxes" name="photography_type[]" id="photography_type">
                                                                                                    <option selected="" value="0" label="General photographer
">General photographer
</option>
                                                                                                                <option value="1" label="Editorial photographer/news photographer 
">Editorial photographer/news photographer 
</option>
                                                                                                                <option value="2" label="Photojournalist">Photojournalist 
</option>

</select>
```

Following is not wprking in IE

```
function removeSelection(id){
        $('#photography_type :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
       $(selected).options[id].selected = false;
        });
 }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to unset selection

This will unset all selected options ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z6mQ/2/)):

```
$('#photography_type :selected').each(function(i, opt) {
    $(opt).prop('selected', false)
})
```

This will remove only one selected element([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z6mQ/3/)):

```
function removeSelection(id){
    $('#photography_type option').eq(id).prop('selected', false)
}
```

Comment: But I need to remove only a specific option with 'id' as index. Is it possible with IE. I'm using IE8+

Comment: @user2919487 better? =)

Comment: @user2919487 if it helped you, don't you want to accept the answer? =)

Answer (score 1):

The `selected` is property of `DOM` object and you are trying to call it with `jQuery` object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vF6vT/1/)**

```
function removeSelection(id) {
    $('#photography_type :selected').each(function (i, selected) {     
        selected.selected = false;
    });
}
```

Or simply, do it in single statement without using `each`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vF6vT/2/)**

```
function removeSelection(id) {
    $('#photography_type :selected').prop('selected', false);
}
```

You can event set the selectedIndex to -1

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vF6vT/3/)**

```
function removeSelection(id) {
    $('#photography_type')[0].selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: Or, for better readability, use `.each(function() {this.selected=false;})`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deselecting every option in a relatively expensive process, just do this:

```
document.getElementById('photography_type').selectedIndex = -1;
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is powerful yet unbeatably efficient and you should use it. ;)